# Java initial value of arraylist of arraylist of float

Tags: java, arraylist

Given the below code

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>> fWordTagProb = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>>();
for(int f=0;f<pennTreeTags.size();f++)
    fWordTagProb.add(new ArrayList<Float>());
```

What is the initial value of each "cell" in this 2d array?
Is it zero?

Hence is it the same for type Integer?

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 5):

Each element of `fWordTagProb` is an empty `ArrayList`. Logically there are nothing yet in the empty lists.

It would be same if you used `Integer` instead of `Float`.

Answer (score 1):

The cells are boxed Floats, and so are reference types.  The default value of a reference type is `null`, and so too is the default value of each cell.

I should add that the sub-ArrayLists are empty, and so there aren't actually any cells at all.  Should the sub-lists be initialized to the desired size, then the cells will indeed be `null`.

Comment: The list is empty, not filled with null. Your answer would apply to an array.

Comment: Updated to reflect the empty list - of course if no capacity is specified there's no allocation and thus no cells.  That's not really what was being asked, though...

Comment: That still is incorrect - even if a capacity is given (the default capacity is not 0 any way) the list is still empty until you add something to it.

Comment: Sure, it's empty in that nothing has been added, but the empty list is backed by an allocated chunk of memory - the Array in ArrayList.  The array contains default values - specifically, `null`.  If you don't believe me, check the source for yourself: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html, line 127.

I think we may be arguing different points.  You're correct that the list is considered to have zero items.  I'm correct in that the backing array contains default values.  Agreed?

Comment: Yes agreed - what I'm trying to say is that it is an inaccessible implementation detail (toArray would still return an empty array for example).

Comment: Agreed.  I could have been more clear - my reading of the question was that the asker wished to know the default value of `Float`.